# Bifurcate Killing Horizon of the Ads-Schwarzschild solution

Tags: general-relativity

I need your help.
I'm considering the AdS-Schwarzschild solution:

$ds^2=V(r)dt^2 + \frac{1}{V(r)}dr^2+r^2dΩ^2$

where $V(r)=1-\frac{2m}{r}+\frac{r^2}{l^2}$ with $m$ the mass of the black hole and $l$ the radius of the AdS spacetime.

Now, given $r=r_+$ one of the roots of the function $V(r)$, I've already shown that $r=r_+$ is a Killing horizon for the Killing vector field $\xi=\partial_t$. What I want to prove also is that $r=r_+$ is a *bifurcate* Killing horizon.
Is there any simple way to do that?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bifurcate Killing horizon is a killing horizon in which the past and future horizons intersect at a point in the Penrose diagram, which is the bifurcation two-sphere. At this point, the generator of the horizon vanishes, which is to say $\xi = 0$ as opposed to being simply null.

In order to show that this is the case in any particular spacetime, you need coordinates which are regular at this intersection point. Here $t$ is ill-defined as a coordinate on the future horizon, so these coordinates are no good. You'll need Kruskal coordinates in order to evaluate this directly.